# Can I display Google map in Tizen wearable web application for Gear 2?

Tags: dictionary, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I know that Gear 2 does not have internet connection but I think this maybe possible if I can use internet connection of mobile device connected to Gear 2 device. Is it possible?

---

#### Solved

I have solved this problem by customizing the LeaftletJS library.

Comment: Does it have to be a Google map?  Have you tried using the JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1):

With the Gear 2 and Gear 2 neo, this is not possible. However, you can create an integrated app that runs on the mobile device, makes internet requests and sends the results to the gear 2.

However, with the new [Gear S](http://denvycom.com/blog/samsung-gears-vs-gear2/), which has wifi, 3g , 4g connections this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be experimenting with the HERE maps by Nokia, I'll let you know of any progress I make (unless you have already figured out the answer)

Comment: @congtrungvnit Do you mean LeafletJS? Have you managed to pass over images via host app to the gear device?

Comment: On gear S I suppose what API are you using for Gear2 ?

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to create a standalone map app for Gear S using Google map JS api. It works fine.

Comment: Ok I'll share only the basic code, not the features added by me. Give me sometime, I'll post the link here.